# Python: Looping through each day for a given month using Calendar(), and find Day-1 and Day+1

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

Need to loop through *any* calendar month and for each date find the day before and day after.

Looping through the month is easy enough, but using this to subtract and add a date proved challenging. Not sure if Calendar can be combined with datetime??

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from calendar import Calendar

cal = Calendar()
for day in cal.itermonthdates(2017, 1):    
   day_minus_one = day - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
   day_plus_one = day - datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
```

Comment: `Calendar` works well with `datetime`, simply drop the `datetime` before `timedelta`

Comment: That was simple enough.. thanks